# Stored procedure with multiple joins with same tables

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

I have this procedure which is trying to load the table5 in oracle environment (11.2) where it's joining with same tables(each has 5 millions of records) for more than 3 times and it's taking more than 2 hours.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC1 AS  
  BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO table4  
 SELECT  
        lt_sn_issues.DA_SECTOR,  
        lt_sn_issues.DA_REGION,  
        tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.PROJ,  
        tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.SOL,  
        COUNT(ft_sn_issues.ISS_ID),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT ft_sn_issues.FL_ID),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT ft_fl_scans.FL_ID),  
        PROJ_files_count.COUNT,  
        COUNT(lt_sn_issues.ISS_ID),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT lt_sn_issues.FL_ID),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT lt_fl_scans.FL_ID),  
        COUNT(pr_sn_issues.ISS_ID),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT pr_sn_issues.FL_ID),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT pr_fl_issues.FL_ID),  
        CURRENT_DATE  
      FROM  
        tmp_ft_lt_scan_id  
        JOIN table1 ft_sn_issues ON ft_sn_issues.SCAN_ID = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID  
        JOIN table1 lt_sn_issues ON lt_sn_issues.SCAN_ID = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID  
        LEFT JOIN table1 pr_sn_issues  
          ON pr_sn_issues.SCAN_ID = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID  
        JOIN table2@dblink ft_fl_scans ON ft_fl_scans.SCAN_ID = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID  
        JOIN table2@dblink lt_fl_scans ON lt_fl_scans.SCAN_ID = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID  
        LEFT JOIN table2@dblink pr_fl_issues ON pr_fl_issues.SCAN_ID = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID  
        JOIN (  
               SELECT  
                 FL_INFOR.PROJ              PROJ,  
                 FL_INFOR.SOL              SOL,  
                 COUNT(DISTINCT FL_INFOR.PATH) COUNT  
               FROM FL_INFOR@DBLINK  
               GROUP BY  FL_INFOR.PROJ,L_INFOR.SOL  
            ) PROJ_files_count  
          ON PROJ_files_count.PROJ = tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.PROJ   
          where rownum<=100  
      GROUP BY  
        lt_sn_issues.DA_SECTOR,  
        lt_sn_issues.DA_REGION,  
        tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.PROJ,  
        tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.SOL,  
       PROJ_files_count.COUNT;
```

Comment: Not just joining the same table of 5m records three times, but the same table **in a remote database**. Oh boy.

Comment: But why are you doing that? The join criteria are the same so it seems you're just selecting the same records three times.

Comment: we are referring three different joins from same tables for retrieving values for 3 different columns and differentiating with alias name.

Comment: But it's the **same set of rows** three times. Not sure what's going on here. Your query joins `table1` three times and `table2@dblink` three times. But always on the same join criterion `tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID` and with no other filter. So the same set of records from each table three times. So either what you have posted here is not your real code, which means there's no chance we'll be able to advise you. Or your query is flawed and generating a massive Cartesian product, which would at least explain why the performance is so poor: too much unnecessary work.

Comment: I have posted the actual code but with different table and column names.How do we avoid massive cartesian product here?

Comment: I don't know your data model, your data or your business rules. So I can't tell you how to re-write your query. If you want us to help you'll need to post some sample data and required output derived from that data so we have a chance of understanding the probelm you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If issue is performance, at first add index to `tmp_ft_lt_scan_id.FIRST_SCAN_ID` column.

Comment: Pure guesswork. Maybe you're right, maybe you're wrong. The OP has provided too little information for anybody to make an informed suggestion. However it looks like they are driving off `tmp_ft_lt_scan_id` and matching rows in the other tables to its rows. So a Full Table Scan on that table would be the right access path, and the best we could hope for from an index is that it doesn't make any difference.